# Implementing cache in a factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, caching, repository-pattern, cachefactory

I'm currently attempting to implement a cache service in my angular application in order to reduce the workload on the end point and to (hopefully) see some slight, probably negligible load times on my interface.

I've started by implementing my own `cacheService` which is pretty much a wrapper for `$cacheFactory`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('cacheService', cacheService);

    cacheService.$inject = ['$cacheFactory']

    function cacheService($cache) {
        return $cache('appCache');
    }
})();
```

Then I have `datacontext` which is essentially a unit of work that consumes my `cacheService` and `$http` (I have several other "repositories" in there but only showed the one I'm attempting to get this to work with)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('datacontext', datacontext);

    datacontext.$inject = ['$http', 'cacheService', '$q'];

    function datacontext($http, cache, $q) {    
        var rulesRepo = (function () {
            var repo = {
                get: getRule,
                getAll: getAll
            };

            return repo;

            function getRule(ruleId) {
                // placeholder
            }

            function getAll() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                // check to see if we have data cached
                var rules = cache.get('rules');
                if (rules) { // if it's cached, return it
                    deferred.resolve(rules);
                } else { // otherwise get the data from the API, cache it and return it
                    $http.get('/api/rules')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            cache.put('rules', response.data);
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);                            
                        });
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        })();    

        var service = {
            rules: rulesRepo
        };

        return service;
    }
})();
```

And then my angular controller that consumes `datacontext`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'datacontext'];

    function HomeController($scope, context) {    
        context.rules.getAll()
            .then(
                function (data) { // success
                    $scope.rules = data;
                },
                function (response) { // failure
                    console.log(response);
                });

        activate();
        function activate() { }
    }
})();
```

The issue I'm facing at the moment is, whenever I make the call to `context.rules.getAll()`, it always hits the `else` statement, meaning `rules` is undefined, so it never uses the cache, it just makes another call to my API, gets the data, caches it (that part works I have tested it by pulling from the cache directly after I put it in the cache), then returns the promise. Over and over.

Can someone point out where I'm not understanding how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

given that all the factories in angular are singletons, the basic cache factory implementation would be something like this

```
app.factory(cacheFactory, function(){
  var localCache = {};
  var put  = function(key, value)     { localCache[key] = value;    }
  var get  = function(key)     { return localCache[key];    }
  return { get:get, put:put  } 
})
```

this should work, unless you want to maintain cache even on hard refresh.

Comment: This seems like a good solution but more of a workaround rather than an answer to my question.